# Terminating MySQLd session to go back to command prompt

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line

I'm using Ubuntu Natty.

I ran mysqld from the command line using the following:

```
mysqld -ndbcluster --console -umysql
```

To which I get the following:

```
120314  0:09:49 [Warning] option 'new': boolean value 'dbcluster' wasn't recognized. Set to OFF.
120314  0:09:49 [Note] Plugin 'ndbcluster' is disabled.
120314  0:09:49 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120314  0:09:50 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120314  0:09:50 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120314  0:09:50 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120314  0:09:50 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
120314  0:09:50 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120314  0:09:50 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120314  0:09:50 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120314  0:09:50  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120314  0:09:51 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120314  0:09:51 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
120314  0:09:51 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.19-ndb-7.2.4-gpl-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Cluster Community Server (GPL)
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to terminate the session. I've tried Control-C and a host of other combinations.

How do I end the session and go back to the command prompt?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will generate `SIGINT`, which can be caught or blocked by the application. If you just run `killall mysqld` from another terminal, you'll send `SIGTERM` to the process, which can also be caught or blocked, but will give a much stronger hint that the process should terminate immediately. (Which will be nice for cleanly closing database tables.)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd></kbd> will generate `SIGQUIT`, which can be caught or blocked by the application. (If the application doesn't catch or block this signal, the OS will generate a core file for you.)</kbd>

You can send a `SIGKILL` by hand using `kill(1)`; `SIGKILL` cannot be caught or blocked, and thus will always terminate a process if the kernel is alive enough to process the signal. Find the pid using `pidof` or another mechanism, and run `kill -SIGKILL pid`. Note that this is a rough death; the process is not given a chance to clean up after itself, so database tables may be left in an inconsistent state that may require some time to repair on the next start.

If you just want a prompt back, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+z to suspend the process. You can then use your shell's `bg` and `fg` commands to allow the process to continue running in the background, or re-join the process in the foreground. (That terminology is non-sense, but I hope it conveys the idea.)

Comment: `Ctrl+\ `  _can_ be caught or blocked by the application. This is easy with `trap 'echo SIGQUIT received' 3`. So this is not `SIGKILL` but `SIGQUIT`. AFAIK there's no keyboard shorctut for `SIGKILL` or `-9` signal.

Comment: @sputnick: amazing, I've gone fifteen years without _checking_ for myself what signal that generates. I've just been happy the process usually dies with it... Thanks mate!

Comment: You can check all of this signals with my script : http://sputnick-area.net/pasteme/316 Simply run the script and try to send some signals by `kill` or by keyboard.

Comment: @sputnick Thanks a lot for this breakdown, very insightful indeed. Cheers.

Comment: On some keyboards, there is no `\ ` key. In such a situation, pressing one of `Ctrl + Shift + <key> `, `Ctrl + Alt + <key> ` or `Ctrl + Right-Alt + <key> ` should work (to generate `SIGQUIT`), where `<key>` is the key that would be pressed in a combination to generate `\ `.

Comment: @rogem, if I had to deal with one of those keyboards I'd probably use `stty(1)` to replace the `kill` key. Well, I'd probably replace the keyboard since it's hard to program in many languages without \. But still.

Answer (score 3):

**Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>**.

MySQL seems to ignore SIGINT (which is emitted when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), but will perform a clean shutdown when it receives SIGQUIT (which is what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> sends).

See samold's answer for details.